# In MS Access VBA, what is the function for returning the time of day? (Not date AND time)

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I get the time of the day in Access VBA? I am trying to build a string to name a file that has a time value in it. I don't want the datetime value, but just the time value. Like the Now() function:

```
CurrentTime = Now()
```

But I only want the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a string value representing time, use the following example:

```
Dim CurrentTime As String
CurrentTime = Time()
```

To pull the time value straight from a variable of type datetime:

```
Dim ExampleDateTime As DateTime
Dim TimeString As String
ExampleDateTime = Now()
TimeString = Format(ExampleDateTime, "mmm d, yyyy h:nn:ss AMPM")
```

Comment: `Time()` does always give you a date component ... *Dec 30, 1899*.  Check `Format(Time(), "mmm d, yyyy h:nn:ss AMPM")`

Comment: But when I enter ?Time() in the Immediate window, I get just the time ex: 2:08:41 PM. Is this different in a VBA module?

Comment: There is no "time only" datatype in Access or VBA.  There is only Date/Time.  So there is always a date component --- if you don't supply that piece, the date component will be zero, which is *Dec 30, 1899*.  Depending on where and how you display a Date/Time value, the zero components (for date or time) may be hidden ... but they're still present in the Date/Time value.

Comment: Take your sample time value and see what you get when you add 10 hours to it --- look at what `DateAdd("h", 10, #2:08:41 PM#)` shows you in the Immediate window.  The *12/31/1899* part had to come from somewhere, right?

Comment: I think I see what you are saying for variable of type datetime. What I meant is to return a value of type string representing the time. I should clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly not use a string variable for datetime. Always - no exceptions - use Date:

```
Dim CurrentTime As Date
CurrentTime = Time
```

Then, for display or reporting, format this as you like.

Comment: See the edited question above. I tried to clarify what I am doing. Does this change your answer at all?

Comment: Sort of. The original code lines should be deleted.